# Can I display only battery percentage in menu bar?

Tags: menu-bar

I'd like to only display the percentage left in the menubar.  It seems that it is more useful than any other battery display option, but it isn't available.

Is there a work-around?

Comment: I'm sure you know you can choose percentage AND battery icon from the drop-down menu. I think the reason behind the icon being there is it's a little less confusing than just seeing a percentage in the menu bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend and use [SlimBatteryMonitor](http://www.orange-carb.org/SBM/) (donation-ware). It's *much* more flexible than what Apple provides.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.  This is a good little app.  A little on the pricey side though.  http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about a Mac, and not an iPhone, iStat Menus 3 is a fantastic application that has a LOT of features, including the one you asked for. In addition to the battery, you can add info to your menu bar such as disk usage, network, internal temp. sensors, and more with graphs and detals.

**For the battery part**, upon clicking on the battery percentage instead of a useless menu you will be presented with information such as battery health, charge cycles, amperage, and cell charges and more, so for only $10 it's a worthwhile investment.

One of my favorite features is the date/time thing which actually shows you a drop down calendar and world clocks. Overall, iStat Menus is definitely worth the $10 lifetime investment. Plus, they give out copies on Twitter (@Bjangocodes and @Bjango) all the time.